# v3.0 not using dual GPU's, 2.82 does (same exact file)

Tags: gpu, performance, system

I've always used 2 GPU's in blender and it's always rendered 2 tiles at a time. Not anymore...

I recently updated to blender 3.0, after about a year of not using it at all. On rendering my first image with it, I note it seems to no longer use both of my GPU's (identical 1070's).

If I load the exact same file in v2.82, it does use both. It renders 2 tiles at a time, no matter if I have SLI enabled or not.

Back in 3.0, only 1 tile at a time.

Can anyone tell me why 3.0 is not using both and how I might fix it?

In both versions, both of the GPU's are enabled for CUDA, they are ticked and not greyed out and I receive no errors.

Comment: Hi :). Blender 3.0 uses Cycles X, a completely redesigned engine, which renders one tile at a time no matter how many cores are computing it. Don't worry, it won't be any slower.